# CentOS7 chrome driver working with Selenuim and Cucumber Not working

Tags: rubygems, cucumber

```
wget https://img.cs.montana.edu/linux/fedora/local/24/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.81-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install google-chrome-stable-58.0.3029.81-1.x86_64.rpm
yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Fonts" "General Purpose Desktop"yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Fonts" "General Purpose Desktop"
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 '1280x1024x16' -ac &> /dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:1export DISPLAY=:1
/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber -t @MYTESTS
```

This made it work with chromedrive 2.29

Comment: Try updating [`chromedriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).  v2.29 supports chrome v56-58, and it looks like you are running v2.25.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Reply. Got it working with v2.29 now